# Good localization framework for Java

Tags: java, frameworks, localization, internationalization

I'm looking for best localization framework for Java. Default localization framework is not enough for me.

Ideally I'm looking for localization framework with following features:

- **Style support** - like [Apache Wicket](https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/localization-and-skinning-of-applications.html) localization framework does
- **Formating support** - dates and numbers format support
- **Plurals support** - like [GWT](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/I18nAnnotations) localization framework does
- **Message hierarchy** - localization finding among hierarchy gained at message level. Typically is lookup path name[style][locale] -> name[locale] -> name[style] -> name, but it is gained at file level - if some message is not in file it wouldn't be translated. I would like to have localization gained at message level.

If you know about some good localization framework, please give me echo. If you think that my requirements are somehow wrong, please let me know also.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for a l10n framework or a web-framework with l10n features?

If your case is the second one, except for the Plurals support, `Apache Tapestry` it's a wonderful choice. :)

http://tapestry.apache.org

Comment: Btw, about the Plurals features, maybe Tapestry has it, I may just haven't seen it.

Comment: I'm looking for stand alone framework with possibility to use it in any application.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at ICU4J.
Especially things like MessageFormat, PluralFormat, SelectFormat to deal with messages, and that can also take care of date/time/number/currency formatting. Or use various formatters directly (DateFormat, NumberFormat, etc.)
ChoiceFormat in Java is also worth a look.

But in general the resource bundles mechanism coupled with MessageFormat is almost always enough (take a look at UResourceBundle in ICU4J, more powerful than the Java ResourceBundle).